# Unable to adjust the secondary axis scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have been trying to plot bar plot and line chart on the same plot using ggplot2 in R, However I have not been able to adjust the secondary axis. Below is how the data looks like.

```
Month       Domestic Visitors   Var1         Var2  Var3     Var4     Var5    Var6       Var7
2016-01-01  140018225              0          0      0        0       0        0        1500
2016-02-01  157837334              0          0      0        0       1473     0        1500
2016-03-01  153520903              0          0      0        0       114      0        1500
2016-04-01  155965472              148935   48575   11324   6075      11319    1200     19468
2016-05-01  133629040              0        74037   11324   19120     41015    1200     24468
2016-06-01  130395546              0        13500    0      12184     3311     1200     16500
2016-07-01  134910131              0          0      0        0       250      8405     1500
2016-08-01  123513886              0          0      0        0       399      8272     1500
2016-09-01  138056952              0          0      4814     0       8354     5612     5612
2016-10-01  156491556              0          0      0        0       740      7975     5724
2016-11-01  123124539              0          0      9603     0       2000     10567    8128
2016-12-01  146472839              0          0      0        0       8046     8087     4334
```

This is how I am trying to plot the data above

```
mdf <- tidyr::gather(mdf, variable, value, -Month, -one_of(colnames(mdf[2])))
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=mdf$value, x = as.Date(mdf$Month), fill = variable), data = mdf,stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y = mdf$Domestic.Visitors, x = as.Date(mdf$Month)), data = mdf,stat="identity", lty = 2) +
  ggtitle("Weekly Spend Timeline") +
  labs(fill = "Channels") +
  scale_x_date(name = "Time Period", labels = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis((~./max(mdf$Domestic.Visitors)))) +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold", hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=12, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=12, face="bold"))
```

Data after gather

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", 
"2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01", "2016-07-01", 
"2016-08-01", "2016-09-01", "2016-10-01", "2016-11-01", "2016-12-01"
), class = "factor"), Domestic.Visitors = c(140018225L, 157837334L, 
153520903L, 155965472L, 133629040L, 130395546L, 134910131L, 123513886L, 
138056952L, 156491556L, 123124539L, 146472839L, 140018225L, 157837334L, 
153520903L, 155965472L, 133629040L, 130395546L, 134910131L, 123513886L, 
138056952L, 156491556L, 123124539L, 146472839L, 140018225L, 157837334L, 
153520903L, 155965472L, 133629040L, 130395546L, 134910131L, 123513886L, 
138056952L, 156491556L, 123124539L, 146472839L, 140018225L, 157837334L, 
153520903L, 155965472L, 133629040L, 130395546L, 134910131L, 123513886L, 
138056952L, 156491556L, 123124539L, 146472839L, 140018225L, 157837334L, 
153520903L, 155965472L, 133629040L, 130395546L, 134910131L, 123513886L, 
138056952L, 156491556L, 123124539L, 146472839L, 140018225L, 157837334L, 
153520903L, 155965472L, 133629040L, 130395546L, 134910131L, 123513886L, 
138056952L, 156491556L, 123124539L, 146472839L), variable = c("Var1", 
"Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var4", 
"Var4", "Var4", "Var4", "Var4", "Var4", "Var4", "Var4", "Var4", 
"Var4", "Var4", "Var4", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", 
"Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var5", "Var6", 
"Var6", "Var6", "Var6", "Var6", "Var6", "Var6", "Var6", "Var6", 
"Var6", "Var6", "Var6", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7", 
"Var7", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7", "Var7"), value = c(1500L, 
1500L, 1500L, 19468L, 24468L, 16500L, 1500L, 1500L, 5612L, 5724L, 
8128L, 4334L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 48575L, 74037L, 13500L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11324L, 11324L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4814L, 0L, 
9603L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6075L, 19120L, 12184L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1473L, 114L, 11319L, 41015L, 3311L, 250L, 399L, NA, 
740L, 2000L, 8046L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1200L, 1200L, 1200L, 8405L, 8272L, 
8354L, 7975L, 10567L, 8087L)), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = "data.frame")
```

I was hoping if some one could please help me figure out what I could be doing wrong and help to plot this data.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: You need to multiply the `y` in `geom_line()` by the same number you divided in `sec.axis()`. Try `geom_line(aes(y = mdf$Domestic.Visitors*max(mdf$Domestic.Visitors)...`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. This might not help as it would result in integer overflow. I tried what you suggested and got the following error `1: In mdf$Domestic.Visitors * max(mdf$Domestic.Visitors) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
3: Removed 301 rows containing missing values (geom_path). `

Comment: If you provide the dataset after `gather` with appropriate variable names, it would be easier for others to try your code on their machines

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang I have update the data as requested

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't make myself clear. Could you please use `dput(mdf)`?

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang I have updated the results. I hope this helps and thanks for the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just start with a simple transformation to put two together.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(y= value, x = as.Date(Month), fill = variable), data = mdf,stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y = (Domestic.Visitors-100000000)/500, x = as.Date(Month)), data = mdf,stat="identity", lty = 2) +
  ggtitle("Weekly Spend Timeline") +
  labs(fill = "Channels") +
  scale_x_date(name = "Time Period", labels = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.+100000000)*500)) +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold", hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=12, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=12, face="bold"))
```

The main y axis is for bar chart of `value` variable and secondary y for the line `Domestic.Visitors`. [image]

You can adjust those values for transformation to re-scale secondary y, for example, if you use 120000000 and 300 instead of 100000000 and 500, the graph looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help here, is it possible to keep my bars at the original scale. Its because that this way the graph shows that the var1, var2...var7 is greater than domestic visitors which does not make business sense. Hence I was hoping if there is a way to keep the axis for bar plot remains the original one

Comment: Thanks a lot.Would wait for the response. Would try myself in the meantime

Comment: I have edited my answer. You may want to adjust those values 100000000 and 500 which I used for re-scaling `Domestic.Vistors` variable

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. That really helped out.

Comment: I am glad it helps